# I have a group task to make a weekly class duty notification app

Tags: android, database

So basically I am in a team of four, (2 backend and 2 frontend) and we are tasked to make an app that notifies the students that are up for the weekly duty. So there's a need for a database that allows the teachers to fill in student names for the week or even update the order of duty. My question is, where do i start with the database and how do i connect them with our app? We use android studio for the app dev and MySQL for the database because of its remote access capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of question is a bit too broad for stackoverflow. You're better off going to a site like [buildfaast](https://buildfaast.com/) to get direction on these types of questions.